# Adding UILabel forces UICollectionViewCell to shrink width

Tags: swift, autolayout, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell, xib

I have a `UICollectionView` with cells that are different widths.

Each cell has a footer view that contains a `UILabel`. I'd like that label to be full width, regardless of how long the text is, I'd like the label to always span the width of the footer view within the `UICollectionViewCell`.

To attempt this I have anchors my `UILabel` as follows -

[image]

To the `top` of the view
To the `trailing` of it's neighbour 
To the `trailing` of the view

The effect of the however is that when my cell is rendered, it is no longer the width set in `sizeForItemAt` and instead is shrunken to the `trailing` edge of the icon.

I cannot understand why, I am new to using a `xib` and historically would build my views programmatically, where I have not encountered this issue.

My `sizeForItem` is -

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return .init(width: collectionView.bounds.width / 2, height: 480)
    }
```

Comment: Do you conform to flowLayout delegate ?

Comment: Yes, my layout works exactly as expected, until I try to anchor a `UILabel` in the `xib`. Without that label the layout is fine

Comment: If I don't anchor to the `trailing` edge it also works, however I am not able to wrap text correctly etc if the line exceeds the width

Comment: leave the leading and trailing as  now , and change horizontal contentHuggingpriority of the label to low most value

Comment: ah perfect, thank you so much

Comment: yes that was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change horizontal `contentHuggingpriority` of the label to low most value so it can stretch freely

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using the center Y and center X constraint and switch the leading and trailing constraints of the label to >=? This should stop the label from disrupting the content size.